# Azure is forcing client to send HTTP Expect 100 Continue with large data requests

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service with WorkerRole that accepts https requests.

IT seems that Azure magic is forcing client to send Expect 100 Continue in an https request header if the payload is > 50KB.

If you send request with data less than 50KB to an Azure https endpoint the server returns the response otherwise the request is timed-out. If Expect 100 Continue is added to the request which is > 50KB the request is accepted.

Any idea why and how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually the client that is in control of this. Your client implementation must be sending an HTTP header like so:

```
Expect: 100-continue
```

Otherwise the server wouldn't bother replying with a 100 Continue status.

If you do not want to use this feature of HTTP/1.1 then simply stop sending the header from your client. In .NET it's turned on by default and you can turn it off for all `HttpWebRequest`s within an `AppDomain` using this static property:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: Hi Drew! I have the Expect100Continue set to false from my service. If I don't send Exect 100 Continue from the client to Azure for payload > 50KB I get http connection timeout error, the server does not respond at all. If payload is <50KB everything is fine. If I add the Expect 100 Continue for the request >50 KB my request is accepted

Comment: Hi @DanDinu could you solve your problem? Our team is getting into the same trouble these days and we don't know how to solve...

Comment: @netblognet didn't manage to fix it in the end unfortunately. I was also in contact with some azure guys with no luck.